# Changing the default directory of a NSOpenPanel to the "Media" directory

Tags: macos, cocoa, directory, media, nsopenpanel

I'm developing a simple app for some students. In the app, a student has to select a video which they made in iMovie. I've already set up a NSOpenPanel for this, but I would like it to default to the movies directory, but not the `~/Movies` directory, I'm aiming for the movies "directory" underneath the media title in Finder. It is a pretty handy directory, because the students will be able to import videos directly from iMovie, instead of having to export and search for them. (Believe me, they screw this up all the time).

For extra clarity, this is a screenshot of the folder as seen in the open sheet:
[image]

(My computer is in dutch, hence the name "Films" instead of "Movies")

Comment: There is an answer for `Pictures`, but that does not seem to work for `Movies`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815183/how-to-access-media-section-photo-movies-directly-from-nsopenpanel-in-mac-os

Comment: @rien333: Did you manage to figure out how to auto-select an item under the 'Media' section as depicted above in the open panel?

Comment: No, I don't think I ever managed to unfortunately.

Comment: This linked question supposedly works tho?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815183/how-to-access-media-section-photo-movies-directly-from-nsopenpanel-in-mac-os?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Unfortunately no. It only opens the `NSOpenPanel` to the location of the Photos library folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URLsForDirectory:inDomains:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory%3ainDomains%3a) method of NSFileManager, passing in the appropriate [NSSearchPathDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory) enumerator value (in your case  NSMoviesDirectory):

```
NSURL* movieDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSMoviesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I just tested this, it opens the `~/Movies` directory, which isn't the directory I'm looking for, as stated in my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit wasn't of much help either, I directly copied your code and it still shows `~/Movies`, which isn't really strange, because, according to the documentation, NSMoviesDirectory is `~/Movies`.