# How to access Media section (Photo & Movies) directly from NSOpenPanel in Mac OS X application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel, iphoto

I already refered this link

[iMedia](https://github.com/karelia/iMedia)

Now i am using NSOpenPanel to open iPhoto library folder.

Here is the code which allow to open.

```
int i = 0;
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.image",@"public.video",nil]];
[openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:TRUE];
[openDlg setAllowsOtherFileTypes:NO];

if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
{
    NSArray *files = [openDlg URLs];
    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
    {
        NSLog(@"File path: %@", [[files objectAtIndex:i] path]);
    }
}
```

This code always open my Finder library folder, As i want to open Media Photo and Movies folder directly.

Please give me any solution.

I have attached here one screen shot.

[image]

Thanks &  Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider adding the following code snipet:

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *picturesURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSPicturesDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:NULL create:NO error:&error];
    NSURL *iPhotoURL = [picturesURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iPhoto Library.photolibrary"];

    [openDlg setDirectoryURL:iPhotoURL];

    // Now run the dialog
```

This won't help if the user has moved his iPhoto library to some non-standard location.

Comment: Your code is working, Thanks a lot. But i can not click on Videos. Any other extra stuff required for that ?

Comment: Now done dude, I have just change allowFileType to @"public.video" replace by @"public.movie" and works..

Comment: Hi jaggie_Gamer! I wanted to do a quick test with an openPanel and the answer aLevelOfIndirection replied you but I didn't have the result like you; My openPanel shows the content of the iPhoto Library package. Did you added any option on you openPanel like setCanChooseDirectories or setTreatsFilePackagesAsDirectories maybe; set both to NO.

Comment: Also did you by any mean tried to extract that view (the one you have once you clicked on the Photos button) and succeeded to do so?

Comment: Go to the finder, and right click on the iPhoto library. Pick "Show Package Contents" and then locate the subdirectory that you need. Append the missing part to the above URL.

Comment: I'm talking about the view displayed on the right of the panel once you have clicked on Photos in media (the one that includes a IKImageBrowserView and an NSOutlineView)

Comment: any updates? I don't see the focus shifting to "media->Photos", I can only see that it opens as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a private API of Apple that contains exactly the control you want to access;
this control is an **ILMediaBrowserView** and provides the exact **same view than the one in NSOpenDialog**. If you are planning an AppStore release of your app don't use it but it can be useful. The framework to integrate to your project to get that view is **iLifeMediaBrowser.framework** in **/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks**.

Comment: @thebenjiman: Do you know if you can set a standard open panel to auto-select the Photos media item so that this browser appears?